# Scaffolding features to implement class hierarchy drilldown/drillup mechanizm

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm trying to live with scaffolding in my grails app and it looks like completely unusable without drilldown/drillup/traversing features over class hierarchy.

When I step into 'onetomany' child entity I completely lose context of the parent and can't stay linked to it when performing 'list' and 'create' operations. But it's absolutely necessary to have such relation for example to create several child objects for the parent or to see only objects related to particular parent when you already created them. It looks like the first feature everyone needed to have when he works with real application...

Please advise what is better way of implementing such behaviour. I'm using latest grails 2.0.1 and now is on the way to customize scaffolding templates for much more level than I expect to be reasonable.

Looking for help in stopping me reinventing the wheel!

Comment: Scaffolding was meant as a get you started process.  Not something you would generally leave in production without modification.  In fact, I never use scaffolding anymore.  I'm not sure there is really an answer to your question.  If you want better scaffolding, create better scaffolding.

Comment: Thanks, Gregg, that's clear, in production for clients i'm using custom pages with very special design and effects. But I also have backside administrative pages to manage data over entities and have no intent to spend lot of time for their development. I'm cosidered scaffolding here as supporting feature that makes my life much easier.

Comment: You could run 'grails install-templates' and modify them to your intent.

Comment: Do your child entities in the 1->M have backreferences to the parent?  That may be part of the issue if you're losing parent object context from the child level.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's great that you are trying to get as much use out of the scaffolding as possible. Scaffolding is a very useful tool and it's a shame that Grails' scaffolding is so poor beyond the initial application development.

One very useful plugin I've found is the [fields plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/fields). It will let you customize the rendering of various elements on your page, and I could see you being able to use that to rather easily maintain the context you are after when drilling down/up your hierarchy.

Unfortunately, you'll likely need to do most of the hard part (maintaining the context) yourself, but at least the fields plugin gives you the tools needed to get there without too much trouble.